# DiscordJS Get Attachment Blob

Tags: javascript, axios, discord, discord.js, blob

I'm trying to get the blob of a Discord message attachment, every time I try an axios request to the CDN, it gets a corrupted blob, however the CDN still lets me download the normal file whenever I go to it.

If this helps this is the file I tried

Raw Upload: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1057112589596889108/1057113515313352704/robloxmodelfile.rbxm

What Axios Gets
https://drive.google.com/file/d/179HKmW2gwGJZmzJYBfDZ3kT2Z15SjD0t/view?usp=sharing
(Sorry I can't upload files to stack overflow)

The after file is about 100kb bigger, which is confusing.
This isn't a database problem because I've tried just turning the blob straight back into an attachment and sending it back, it's still always a bigger file and never opens. However they look similar in notepad++

This is how I get the attachment:

```
let file = await axios({
    url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1057112589596889108/1057113515313352704/robloxmodelfile.rbxm', 
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob',
}).then((response) => {
    return response.data
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResponseType `'blob'` only works on browser axios, use `arraybuffer` instead.